# Split dataframe list column dealing with NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a dataframe with a column where all its elements are lists but some elements are NaN. Something like this:

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | 0, 16 |
| 02/01/2022 | 0, 22 |
| 03/01/2022 | 0, 15 |
| 04/01/2022 | 0, 2 |
| 05/01/2022 | NaN |

I'm trying to separate the values in two others columns, one for each data of the list with the pandas function to_list. But I can't do it works having NaN in the column. I could do dropna but I need the date data. My intention is to replace NaN with 0, 0.

At the end what I want to achieve is this result, no matter how to get there:

| Date | Value | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | 0, 16 | 0 | 16 |
| 02/01/2022 | 4, 22 | 4 | 22 |
| 03/01/2022 | 8, 15 | 8 | 15 |
| 04/01/2022 | 8, 2 | 8 | 2 |
| 05/01/2022 | NaN | 0 | 0 |

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

In your case just do split

```
out = df.join(df['Value'].str.split(', ',expand=True).fillna(0))
#df['Value'].str.split(', ',expand=True).fillna(0)
Out[34]: 
   0   1
0  0  16
1  0  22
2  0  15
3  0   2
4  0   0
```

Comment: why first column is all `0`?

Comment: @QuangHoang you can check his input and output ~ I think the mismatch come from his data

Comment: Thanks for this, but it works if the values were string. In this case they are lists

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `Value` column is in fact type `list`, not `str`, you could:

```
df[["A", "B"]] = df["Value"].apply(pd.Series).fillna(0)
```

Comment: Your method is far better than what I had in mind. Could you explain why `.apply(pd.Series)` works here please? Can it detect the number of elements inside in the list and create corresponding number of pandas series from the lists? Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html . It mentions by the return value that if the applied function returns a pd.Series, the output of func applied to all elements in the series (df["Value"]) will be a pd.DataFrame. You can use that frame to assign to the new columns A and B.

Comment: Just reread your comment, pd.Series is not applied to "vertically" (i.e. creates only two series), it is applied horizontally (i.e., it creates a small pd.Series for each list in the column).

Comment: It works for me but it takes too much time to be completed. I have 1 million of rows.

Answer (score 1):

I think Chrysophylaxs's and BENY's answers are much better than mine but I will chime in with my solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = [['01/01/2022', [0, 16]],
                         ['02/01/2022', [0, 22]],
                          ['05/01/2022', np.nan]
                         ], columns = ['date', 'value'])

def split_value(row):
    try:
        return pd.Series({'value_A': row['value'][0], 'value_B': row['value'][1]})
    except:
        return pd.Series({'value_A': 0, 'value_B': 0})

df[['value_A', 'value_B']] = df.apply(split_value, axis=1)
```

This will return result

```
date    value   value_A value_B
0   01/01/2022  [0, 16] 0   16
1   02/01/2022  [0, 22] 0   22
2   05/01/2022  NaN     0   0
```